# how to fake click md-slide-toggle in jasmine test

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I want to test isMultipleInvoice state turns false with the toggle click. I simulate toggle click calling `dispatchEvent`, `triggerEventHandler` with `click`, `input`, `change` but isMultipleInvoice state is always true. I have included everything I tried in comment lines.

view:

```
<md-slide-toggle class="gregreger" [(ngModel)]="isMultipleInvoice">Default Name & Address</md-slide-toggle>
```

test:

```
it('should to be false isMultipleInvoice', fakeAsync(() => {

expect(component.isMultipleInvoice).toBeTruthy("isMultipleInvoice must true")
    let toggle = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".gregreger"))

    toggle.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
    //toggle.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
    //toggle.triggerEventHandler("change",null)
    //toggle.nativeElement.click()
    //document.createEvent('Event');

    fixture.detectChanges()
    tick()
    //tick(500)
expect(component.isMultipleInvoice).toBeFalsy("toggle should update model")
}))
```

Comment: you can access the dom element and click the element

Comment: How exactly please?